# placeholder attribute in zf2 problems

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I cant get  the value in the placeholder,the placeholder is empty

```
<div class="form_element">
<?php 

    //$name = $form->get('name');

    $this->placeholder('name')->data="text value";
    $name= $form->get('name');
    echo $formLabel->openTag().$name->getOption('label')." ";
    echo $this->formInput($name);
    echo $formLabel->closeTag();
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code you used `placeholder` view helper ([more about](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.placeholder.html)), and I don't see where you trying to get placeholder's value. It seems you asked about form input field placeholder attribute. If it true, then you must specify it as attribute. View helper `placeholder` is for different tasks.

Your form view helpers usage a little strange. May suggest my version of your code.

```
<div class="form_element">

    <?php $name = $form->get('name'); ?>
    <?php $name->setAttribute('placeholder', 'placeholder text'); ?>

    <?php echo $formLabel($name); ?>
    <?php echo $formInput($name); ?>
</div>
```

The better solution is to set placeholder in form element definition. For example:

```
<?php

use Zend\Form\Form;

class MyForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('<FORM_NAME>');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'attributes' => array(
                'placeholder' => '<PLACEHOLDER_TEXT>',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```